# jQuery attribute selector unrecognized expression error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following code to select the list item for current page from a navigation unordered list, but I keep getting an unrecognized expression error on `'a[href$="{server-relative URL}"]'`

I've checked matching quotes/brackets that other questions mention, and the link will not contain characters beyond the usual `/ & ? %` The code I'm using is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var pathname = window.location.pathname;
    var selector = "'a[href$=\"" + pathname + "\"]'";
    var listItem = $(selector).parent().parent();
    listItem.addClass('selected');
});
```

I'm using jQuery 1.8.2 (latest version). Thanks!

Comment: Why `"'`, when only one delimiter (either `"` or `'`) should be enough?

Comment: Double check your quotes, that's the problem right there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you're surrounding your selector in single quotes. Just change this line:

```
var selector = "'a[href$=\"" + pathname + "\"]'";
```

...to this:

```
var selector = 'a[href$="' + pathname + '"]';
```

Comment: Note - adress with slashes has to be in the quotes :) eg. this will work: [id=song1] but this will not:[id=songs/song01.mp3], so you just have to make it [id="songs/song01.mp3"] :)